# Jquery datepicker fixed maxrange 365 days between 2 inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 2 jQuery datepicker inputs

And I set default settings on like this:

```js
$("#polis_date_from").datepicker({
  uiLibrary: "bootstrap4",
  changeYear: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  dateFormat: "yy.mm.dd",
  yearRange: "-0:+1"
});

$("#polis_date_to").datepicker({
  uiLibrary: "bootstrap4",
  changeYear: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  dateFormat: "yy.mm.dd",
  maxDate: "+365d"
});

$("#polis_date_from").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="polis_date_from" placeholder="YYYY.mm.dd" />
<input id="polis_date_to" placeholder="YYYY.mm.dd" />
```

But the problem is that person can change date in `#polis_date_from` datepicker, from example: 2024.09.09 .

And the second datepicker `#polis_date_to` still will have `maxRange` from today + 365d.

How to change dynamically maxDate to always be +365d from the date in `#polis_date_from`?

I've tried to write this but that didn't work:

```
$("#polis_date_from").on("change", async function(e) {
    var today = new Date().getTime();

    var polis_date_from_date = new Date($("#polis_date_from").val()).getTime();

    var timeDiff = Math.abs(polis_date_from_date - today)

    var daysDiff = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24))

    $("#polis_date_to").datepicker({
        maxDate: `+${365 + daysDiff}d`
    });
})
```

Comment: Please show us what you actually tried, instead of just telling us _that_ you tried something & it did not work as intended.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: I added code example what i actually tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user select date on your `#polis_date_from` datepicker, get that date and add a year to it. And set this value the `maxDate` on you `#polis_date_to` datepicker. See the following example.

```js
$("#polis_date_from").datepicker({
  uiLibrary: "bootstrap4",
  changeYear: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  dateFormat: "yy.mm.dd",
  yearRange: "-0:+1",
  onSelect: function() {
    var maxDate = $('#polis_date_from').datepicker('getDate');
    maxDate.setFullYear(maxDate.getFullYear() + 1);
    $("#polis_date_to").datepicker("change", {
      maxDate: maxDate
    });
  }
});

$("#polis_date_to").datepicker({
  uiLibrary: "bootstrap4",
  changeYear: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  dateFormat: "yy.mm.dd",
  maxDate: "+365d"
});

$("#polis_date_from").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="polis_date_from" placeholder="YYYY.mm.dd" />
<input id="polis_date_to" placeholder="YYYY.mm.dd" />
```

Comment: when I try to choose date of next month in "polis_date_from", "polis_date_to" can't choose more, than 0 days, that means that i can only pick today date for "polis_date_to".

Comment: I don't understand your issue, can you clarify it more clearly what you want to achieve?

Comment: You mean your minimum date must be the value of `polis_date_from` ?

Comment: I tried to remove from  "maxDate.setFullYear(maxDate.getFullYear() + 1);" "+1" and it caused problems (can't choose day more, than +0 day), but if I keep it, then I got 366 max days that can be keeped.
Example: 2023.09.09 + 365days = 2024.09.08, not 2024.09.09

Comment: instead of `maxDate.setFullYear(maxDate.getFullYear() + 1)` you can add days with `maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 365);` also

Comment: If you want to count today as day 1, I guess you need to add 364 days.